# Changing Tomcat logging not working as expected

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I have a misbehaving application running under Tomcat on MSWindows. To set up the system to give better insight into what is failing, I am trying to add GC logging - but thus far my attempts have failed.

Initially I had set CATALINA_OPTS in setenv.bat - but these were ignored on restarting the service.

I then tried adding the options using Tomcat8w.exe :

```
-Xloggc:"C:\PerfLogs\gc-tomcat.log"
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=5M 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-verbose:gc
-XX:+PrintGCDateStamps 
-XX:+HeapDumpOnCtrlBreak
```

The service fails to start with "error 4". Event viewer shows:

> The Apache Tomcat 8.0 Tomcat8 service terminated with the following service-specific error: 
>   The system cannot open the file.

I have checked the path and the SYSTEM user has full control. There are no errors reports in the Tomcat stderr log - only a single entry:

```
Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
```

I see nothing being added to the other log files.

Removing the options above allows the service to start. Using the above config with the double quotes on the path has no impact. Creating the initial log file before starting the service has no impact.

How do I enable GC logging? How can I find out why this is currently failing?

(sadly, migrating to a more user friendly operating system is not an option).

**Update**
I found some more log entries - this time in common-daemon-YYYY-MM-DD.log:

```
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [info]  [ 4068] Running 'Tomcat8' Service...
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [info]  [ 2560] Starting service...
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [error] [ 4200] CreateJavaVM Failed
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [error] [ 4200] The system could not find the environment option that was entered.
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [error] [ 2560] Failed to start Java
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [error] [ 2560] ServiceStart returned 4
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [info]  [ 4068] Run service finished.
[2018-08-29 11:04:52] [info]  [ 4068] Commons Daemon procrun finished
```

and, in case it is relevant:

```
java version "1.8.0_74"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a good deal of digging around, I found that the MSWindows jvm is a apparently a second rate citizen in the Java world. According to the [Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) the MSWindows Java engine does not support log rotation. Removing the following options from the config allowed the JVM to start with GC logging:

```
-XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation 
-XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10 
-XX:GCLogFileSize=5M
```

Why this reported as "The system cannot open the file", I have no idea.

Now I just need to work out what happens when the log files fill up / how I prevent this.